# Duplicate Yeoman application

Tags: ember.js, yeoman

I use [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) to build [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) applications.

I want to duplicate an application (changing the directory and application name (which means changing the name in all Ember views, controllers, etc.).

At the moment I'm doing everything manually, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in tool in Yeoman, but if your app name is unique, you can just replace it in all your files by running something like this:

`git ls-files | egrep '\.(js|html)$' | xargs sed -i s/OldAppName/NewAppName/g`

Comment: Sorry i cannot understand this; why i need the command git? I'm using yeoman to build my app locally on a windows machine; so i can't run egrep or xargs...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't give you a hint how to do this on Windows. You probably want to use cygwin or something to get a proper shell, anyway. And regarding git: You don't need it, but it's handy. You can replace the first two segments with `find . -name '*.js' -o -name '*.html'`.